# Existence of a prime between $ap$ and $(a+1)p$ - generalization of Bertrand's postulate

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

Conjecture:

> There exists at least one prime number $p_{m}$ : $ap_{n} < p_{m} < (a+1)p_{n}$,  $\forall$ $a \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\forall$ $p_{n}$ $\in \mathbb{P} $ if $(a+1)p_{n} < p_{n+1}^2$ .

Is there a name for this conjecture, and has it been proven or disproven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bertrand's postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) says that there is always a prime between $n$ and $2n$ for any $n$. So for $a=1$, your conjecture is a special case of this (and you don't need that $(a+1)p_n<p_{n+1}^2$ hypothesis). Note that at the end of that article, it says it has only recently been proven that there is always a prime between $2n$ and $3n$, and between $3n$ and $4n$, so your conjecture is true for $a=2$ and $a=3$ as well (and again, without needing that extra hypothesis). I don't know about the general case (or if there is a name for it), but you might want to start by seeing if the techniques developed for those latter cases can be adapted to prove what you want.

Comment: The even more general case of my conjecture; saying that there always exists a prime number between $ap_{n}$ and $(a+1)p_{n+1}$, without the condition that they are less than $p^2_{n+1}$ - is definitely not true, (let $a=2141$ and $n=13$).

Comment: Between $27833$ and $27846$, which are both multiples of $13$, every intermediate number is divisible by one of $2$, $3$,$ 5$, $7$, or $11$.